# Does Twilio.Client.activeConnection() actually exist?

Tags: javascript, client, twilio

From the [docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/device)

> .activeConnection()
>
> Returns the active connection object. Connection objects can be used
>   to perform operations on the connection like mute, unmute, sending
>   DTMF digits, etc.

Maybe I'm crazy but it certainly seems like this doesn't actually exist. I can't use it from the console, and I don't even see it anywhere in the twilio.js file. (I checked the pre-loader and the actual code)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

It may be that this was added in the newly release version 1.2 the TwilioClient for JavaScript   SDK.  Can you [check to make sure](https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/twilio-js#including-js) that is the version you are running?

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it.  I did actually check if there was a new version but couldn't find it — this page still shows v1.1: http://www.twilio.com/client/api

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I just let the website team know about the issue, so we'll get it corrected asap.  Sorry for the confusion.